# Running python script from terminal on MacOS requires

Tags: python, macos, shell

I have a cli with a few functions that i copy into `/local/bin` using:

`sudo ln -s ~/code/project/scripts/sl /usr/local/bin/sl`

If I activate the virtual env and do `sl command_name service` it works as expected.

But if try to run it from terminal I get:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-USER ~ % sl command_name service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sl", line 4, in <module>
    from sl_commands.sl import execute
  File "/Users/user/code/project/scripts/sl_commands/sl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import argh
ImportError: No module named argh
```

Running pip3 install argh results in:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-USER ~ % pip3 install argh
Requirement already satisfied: argh in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.26.2)
```

If I try the same on ubuntu the script executes correctly. How do i make it run on MacOS without activating a virtualenv?

Comment: Looks like the script doesn't agree with `pip3` on which Python libraries to use. Do you set `PYTHONPATH`? What's the shebang of the script and if that's not an absolute path, what does it resolve to? Can you dump the value of `sys.path` from within the script as part of the traceback?

Comment: @tripleee It was the shebang. I had it as `#! /usr/bin/env python` but it needs `python3` for MacOS

Answer (score 0):

The shebang needs to be `#! /usr/bin/env python3` and not python. Since python2 is 'python' on MacOS

Comment: I think instead of changing shebang, create symlink python 2 python3  under /usr/local/bin/

`$ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3  /usr/local/bin/python`

And set PATH variable,
`$export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`